# Hp nonstop utility like EMSPERUS

Tags: tandem

Is there any HP provided utility similar to one EMSPERUS (this is by ACI) ?
I know Viewpoint but that is kind of just for GUI but I wanted to use in TACL macro to extract ems messages.

I know we can develop utility simlar to Emsperus using SPI programming but that will take time. Please let me know if anyone of you is aware about such existing utility.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know very much about it, but you may be able to use "esmdist" for this. You'll have to find the syntax yourself as I don't have that info here.

Comment: This should be a comment rather, since it does not provide a definitive answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say exactly what you want the TACL macro to do.  Here's the one I used to display EMS events.

```
== @Display EMS events@
?TACL MACRO
#FRAME
#PUSH error endtime outfile
#SETMANY error, [#DEFINEINFO =_ems_templates]
[#IF [error] |THEN|
  Add define =_ems_templates,class map,file $wrkm01.richx.newnres
]
[#IF [#EMPTY %2%] |THEN|
  #SET endtime eof
|ELSE|
  #SET endtime %2%
]
[#IF [#EMPTY %3%] |THEN|
  #SET outfile [#MYTERM]
|ELSE|
  #SET outfile %3%
]
emsdist type p, collector $MALG, textout [outfile], &
  filter \mboxdev.$work.richems.mailfilt,time %1%,stop [endtime]
#UNFRAME
```

Answer (score 0):

I was first thinking of using the Tandem FUP utility, but then I found this TACL document which also discusses EMS in detail. Also,  FYI TACL is Tandem's interpretative language. We used that to run our Tandem processes.   via Batchcom.

http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.BINARYPORTLET/public/kb/docDisplay/resource.process/?spf_p.tpst=kbDocDisplay_ws_BI&spf_p.rid_kbDocDisplay=docDisplayResURL&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&spf_p.rst_kbDocDisplay=wsrp-resourceState%3DdocId%253Demr_na-c02133195-1%257CdocLocale%253D&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken